# Model rule variable required without scenario (Yii2)

Tags: validation, model, yii2, rule, customvalidator

How can I create a model rule that's only required when a certain value from the Database is 1?

I tried using a `'required', 'when'` rule but that doesn't seem to update the client-side JavaScript.

I also tried a custom inline validator but that doesn't seem to post an empty field.

Scenario's aren't an option I think as I have 6 fields and can have any combination of required/not required.

## EDIT

At the moment I just never add the required rules, instead of directly returning the rules I store them in a variable. `$rules = []`

Then before I return the variable I add the required options to the array.
`if($x->x_required)
    $rules[] = ['your-field', 'required', 'on' => 'your-scenario'];`

This is a quickfix and I don't really like it, but it works. I'm not sure if there is a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use combination `required` with `when`, but for client side validation you need additionally specify `whenClient` property.

Example (add this to your `rules()`):

```
[
    'attributeName',
    'required',
    'when' => function ($model) {
        return $model->country == Country::USA;
    },
    'whenClient' => function (attribute, value) {
        return $('#country').value == 'USA';
    },
],
```

**Official docs:**

- [RequiredValidator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-requiredvalidator.html)
- [Validator $when](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-validator.html#$when-detail)
- [Validator $whenClient](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-validator.html#$whenClient-detail)

Comment: `return $('#country').value == 'USA';` this part is what I don't understand, as it needs to be required on not depending on a Database value. How could you check for that in Javascript? Btw, it just needs to be required or not on pageload and doesn't have to be live if that makes it any easier.

Comment: Could you provide more detailed example?

Comment: In this case, I have a 'settings' table in my DataBase, and it has a couple of columns like 'x_required', 'y_required'. Want I want to accomplish is to have the form field be required if the column has a value of '1'. That's my problem here, as your example seems to check other fields for it to be required or not.

Comment: This example shows how to set attribute required only when another attribute has certain value. Alternatively you can check value of this attribute, so I don't see problem here.